# If $\alpha^3 - 3\alpha^2 + 5\alpha -17 =0 $ and $\beta^3 - 3\beta^2 + 5\beta+11 =0 $ then find value of $\alpha+\beta$($\alpha,\beta$ is real number)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The curve $y = x^3 - 3x^2 + 5x $ is a strictly increasing curve. $y=x^3 - 3x^2 + 5x -17 =0 $ intersect x axis between 3 and 4. $y=x^3 - 3x^2 + 5x +11 =0 $ intersect x axis between -2 and -1. The answer is given 2. Is it possible find exact value  of $\alpha+\beta$

Comment: Yes, it is possible to find the exact value; one way uses resultants, but that's likely beyond the method you would like given the tags on the question.  Also, perhaps define $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the question and not just in the title.

Comment: you can solve a cubic equation by the formulas of Cardano

Comment: I checked it using resultants, $2$ is a value for $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: Substitute $y=2-x$ in the first equation and you get the second equation.

Answer (score 4):

Write
$$f(x)=x^3-3x^2+5x=(x-1)^3+2(x-1)+3.\tag1$$
From (1) we see that $f(x)-3$ is a sum of odd powers of $x-1$, so $f$ is rotationally symmetric about $(1,3)$. This can be expressed
$$f(1+x)+f(1-x)=6\ \text{for every $x$.}\tag2$$
Since $f$ is strictly increasing, (2) implies that(*)
$$\text{$u+v=2$ whenever $f(u)+f(v)=6$.}\tag3$$
To answer the original question, note that $f(\alpha)+f(\beta)=17+(-11)=6$.

Proof of (*): If $f(u)+f(v)=6$, then let $x:=u-1$. Then $$f(1-x)\stackrel{(2)}=6-f(1+x)=6-f(u)=f(v).$$ Since $f$ is one-to-one, we deduce $1-x=v$ and so $u+v=(1+x)+(1-x)=2$.